# Overlapping labels after setMinMax() function at teechart java

Tags: java, teechart

I created a chart with custom axes and a simple line that uses a vertical and a horizontal axis out of them. Next I zoomed in by calling the `setAutomatic(false`) and `setMinMax(min, max)` method provided by the `Axis` class. TeeChart zoomed in, but it behaves different in comparison to a normal zoom-in. It does not rescale the axis labels - why? How to rescale axis labels so that they do not overlap?

After debugging I found out, that after a normal zoom-in the method invalidate() is called next. So I also tried to call `doInvalidate()` on my teechart instance, but that didn't help. `setMinorTickCount(arg0)` and `adjustMinMax()` changed also nothing.

Any idea how to re-scale labels? Thx

Here is how you can reproduce it:

```
TChart chart = new TChart(parent, 0);
Line series = new Line(chart.getChart());
series.fillSampleValues(100);

chart.getAxes().getBottom().setAutomatic(false);
chart.getAxes().getBottom().setMinMax(0.0, 10.0);
chart.getAxes().getBottom().setMinMax(2.0, 5.0);
```

I need something like I get, when I scroll after this operations. After a scroll the labels re-scale properly.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Same as [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=14380&start=0).

First of all note the `setMinMax()` function already sets `automatic` to `false`, so you don't need to call `setAutomatic(false)` before calling `setMinMax()`.
Also, calling `setMinMax()` function twice, only the last call makes sense, and I don't see any different behaviour adding or removing the first one.

I've seen your code seems to produce a chart with overlapping labels int he bottom axis. That's strange because if I scroll the chart a bit, or I set a slightly different minimum and maximum, the overlap doesn't appear:

```
tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setMinMax(2.01, 5.01);
```

I've added it to the wish list to be revised for next releases (TJ71016731).

---

**UPDATE:**

As a workaround, you could manually set an `Increment` as follows:

```
tChart1.getAxes().getBottom().setIncrement(0.5);
```